# Removing an ECR image while Fargate cluster relies on it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I am wondering what would happen if I remove an ECR image where we have an AWS Fargate cluster live based on that image.

- Would live containers stop working?
- Would autoscaling fail to create new instances?

This is because we want to implement lifecycle policies and I want to know if we should take precautions against expiring an image while we have a cluster deployed that is using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would live containers stop working?

No. The live containers would continue to run.

> Would autoscaling fail to create new instances?

Yes. You would not be able to deploy any new containers that use that image.

> This is because we want to implement lifecycle policies and I want to
> know if we should take precautions against expiring an image while we
> have a cluster deployed that is using it.

Yes, you absolutely want to take precautions to keep the current image that your deployment depends on, or the next auto-scaling event, or replacement of a crashed container, will fail.