# Avoid expiring any ECR image if an ECS cluster is still referencing it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, amazon-ecr

We are implementing lifecycle policies to clean up old ECR images but we want [to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323604/removing-an-ecr-image-while-fargate-cluster-relies-on-it) expiring any image if a Fargate ECS cluster is still referencing it. How can we best do that?

I am thinking about adding a "live" tag that is being set and unset by the Blue-Green Switch, but there is a problem - 2 or more environments in our AWS CodePipeline might be using the same image so I would need to implement some kind of reference counting.

Is there a better way, or should I go with this approach?

Comment: Is everything in the same account, or are you accessing images across account?

Comment: Everything is on the same account

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately using lifecycle rules to manage images is just not ideal with AWS.

- Multiplatform images (amd64 + arm64) are managed in registries by having a top level meta image that points to other images depending on platform (this is a bit of a simplification). When you tag your image it only tags the top level meta one, not the lower level ones. As such it's possible to accidentally erase images.
- As you've discovered images can be erased even if they are referenced somewhere.

Instead of using lifecycle rules I use a simple script, which in turn includes any logic I want. You can run a filter to see what ECS services exist and are using the image and then exclude any where that comes back empty. This is much simpler if everything is in the same account.

To put this another way- instead of having your services push tags to your images, have your deletion script explicitly confirm that no images which are being used get deleted. Then you don't have to worry about how many environments are running it.

Comment: Actually after reading in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/lifecycle_policy_examples.html) it seems it should be possible using rules order ([see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oemwC.png)). So I can just have a rule for tag "prod" tag with count=1, same for "staging" and "dev", and then expire everything in 6 months afterwards. An image seen by one rule cannot be discarded by the next, it seems.

Comment: As long as you aren't using multiarch images that's fine, but remember what I said about tags here.

Comment: There is an open GitHub issue about the ECR UI experience showing multiple images and problems with setting up Lifecycle policies for multi-architecture images, in case anybody is looking for that: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1596, mentioned also in https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/940#issuecomment-1043198683